# DateTime.Now.ToString() wrong/funny result

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a strange C# (4.7.2) behavior.
One PC has this problem.
Calling the :

```
DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

returns

> '05/mm/42/mm/2020 11:42:54.3784272'

And calling :

```
return $"to_date('{datetime:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')";
```

Returns

> '03/mm/05/mm/2020 11:03:00'.

I have checked that `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat` is not changed in the program. So the default format of the system is used.

Thnx

Edit
Running Powershell on the machine the command

```
(Get-culture).DateTimeFormat
```

Returns:

```
AMDesignator                     : AM 
Calendar                         : System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar DateSeparator                 : -
FirstDayOfWeek                   : Sunday 
CalendarWeekRule         : FirstDay
FullDateTimePattern              : d MMMM, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
LongDatePattern                  : d MMMM, yyyy 
LongTimePattern       : h:mm:ss tt 
MonthDayPattern                  : MMMM d 
PMDesignator   : PM
RFC1123Pattern                   : ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss
'GMT' ShortDatePattern                 : dd-MMM-yy
ShortTimePattern   : h:mm tt 
SortableDateTimePattern          : yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss
TimeSeparator                    : :
UniversalSortableDateTimePattern : yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'
YearMonthPattern                 : MMMM yyyy
AbbreviatedDayNames     : {Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed...} 
ShortestDayNames                 : {Su, Mo,Tu, We...}
 DayNames                         : {Sunday, Monday,Tuesday, Wednesday...} AbbreviatedMonthNames            : {Jan, Feb,Mar, Apr...} 
MonthNames                       : {January, February,March, April...} 
IsReadOnly                       : False
NativeCalendarName               : Gregorian Calendar
AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames    : {Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr...}
MonthGenitiveNames               : {January, February, March,April...}
```

**EDIT**

Simple program shows something is not ok with DateTime formatting

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime aDate = DateTime.Now;
     var formats = new List<string>
    {
        "MM/dd/yyyy",
        "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy",
        "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss",
        "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm",
        "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt",
        "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm",
        "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt",
        "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
        "MMMM dd",
        "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff",
        "ddd, dd MMM yyy HH:mm:ss GMT",
        "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss",
        "HH:mm",
        "hh:mm tt",
        "H:mm",
        "h:mm tt",
        "HH:mm:ss",
        "yyyy MMMM"
    };
     Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
     foreach (var format in formats)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{format.PadRight(50)} \t" + aDate.ToString(format));
    }

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture= CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
    foreach (var format in formats)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{format.PadRight(50)} \t" + aDate.ToString(format));
    }
     Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Returns result as :

```
> en-US en-US MM/dd/yyyy                                             
> 03-05-2020 dddd, dd MMMM yyyy                                     
> Thursday, 05 March 2020 dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss                   
> Thursday, 05 March 2020 15:36:12 MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm                     
> 03-05-2020 15:36 MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt                                  
> 03-05-2020 03:36 PM MM/dd/yyyy H:mm                                   
> 03-05-2020 15:36 MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt                                   
> 03-05-2020 3:36 PM MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss                                
> 03-05-2020 15:36:12 MMMM dd                                           
> March 05 yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff                            
> 2020-03-05T15:36:12.5532993 ddd, dd MMM yyy HH:mm:ss GMT              
> Thu, 05 Mar 2020 15:36:12 G3T yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss                     
> 2020-03-05T15:36:12 HH:mm                                             
> 15:36 hh:mm tt                                                03:36 PM
> H:mm                                                    15:36 h:mm tt 
> 3:36 PM HH:mm:ss                                               
> 15:36:12 yyyy MMMM                                               2020
> March en-US en-US MM/dd/yyyy                                          
> 03/05/2020 dddd, dd MMMM yyyy                                     
> Thursday, 05 March 2020 dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss                   
> Thursday, 05 March 2020 15:36:12 MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm                     
> 03/05/2020 15:36 MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt                                  
> 03/05/2020 03:36 PM MM/dd/yyyy H:mm                                   
> 03/05/2020 15:36 MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt                                   
> 03/05/2020 3:36 PM MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss                                
> 03/05/2020 15:36:12 MMMM dd                                           
> March 05 yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff                            
> 2020-03-05T15:36:12.5532993 ddd, dd MMM yyy HH:mm:ss GMT              
> Thu, 05 Mar 2020 15:36:12 G3T yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss                     
> 2020-03-05T15:36:12 HH:mm                                             
> 15:36 hh:mm tt                                                03:36 PM
> H:mm                                                    15:36 h:mm tt 
> 3:36 PM HH:mm:ss                                               
> 15:36:12 yyyy MMMM                                               2020
> March
```

As you can see same culture is used, same formats are used.
But in first run any'/' are converted to '-'.
That is not happening on second run after setting culture.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209122/discussion-on-question-by-gintaras-datetime-now-tostring-wrong-funny-result).

Comment: @SamuelLiew and once again, a lot of important information, especially the steps in the investigation are lost. What was tried and not, is lost. The answer is now in-answerable.

Comment: Let's put back the lost information. 1) The Culture and UICulture behave differently, even though they have the same name. This can't be reproduced on other machines, so it's quite possible a *custom* culture setting, or full out custom culture is used, either in the app itself or *Windows*.

Comment: 2) The problem appears while trying to use date literals in an Oracle query. There are no more details about the .NET version (not ever Core vs Old), the OS version or the driver used.  Bobby Tables aside, this could be caused by an Oracle HOME setting that tries to "fix" the inherent conversion issues when string concatenation is used.

Comment: 3) To isolate the problem, we need to check the app and *.NET* separately. One step is to use Powershell and  run `Get-culture` **AND** `Get-UICulture`. Just `(Get-culture).DateTimeFormat` isn't enough. Comparing *both* results would show if there's any difference between cultures, even if the names are the same. If there *is*, we know the cultures have been modified.

Comment: 4) `Culture` **has** been modified. `dd-MMM-yy` is *not* the short date format in the US. It should be `M/d/yyyy`. So we have *proof* that a custom culture is used, we don't know if that's due to user locale settings or a custom culture though

Comment: 5) [Custom cultures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8#custom-cultures) are possible and [installable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder?view=netframework-4.8). A custom culture can replace a built-in one simply by using the same name. Custom cultures have different LCID and CultureTypes values, which is why all the CultureInfo properties are needed. Installed cultures are stored in `%windir%\Globalization`

Comment: 6) To get *all* CultureInfo properties use `Get-culture |Format-List -Property *` and `Get-UICulture |Format-List -Property *`. This isn't recursive though

Comment: 7) `05/mm/42/mm/2020 11:42:54.3784272` looks like the result of a botched short date pattern, one that used `mm` (minutes)` instead of `MM` (months), and probably *surrounded* the actual format specifiers with some literals. A human modifying the local user settings would detect that. I suspect this was caused by *code* that generated multiple custom cultures in a loop

Comment: 8) A custom Culture would affect what `Get-Date -Format ' produces. We already know that `CurrentCulture` in the *app* is affected. What is the result of `Get-Date -Format G` (the Generic format used by `ToString()`), `Get-Date -Format d` (short date pattern) and `Get-Date -Format 'MM/dd/yyyy'` (explicit short format)? If `d` is different from the explicit format, we know what pattern was modified

Comment: 9) Is the machine a normal Windows installation, or a customized Windows Embedded version? In that case the customizations may go deeper and not appear in the `Globalization` folder

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an answer, just a copy of the investigation comments, in case they get deleted again. If I had to give an answer, it would be to :

- Find what customizations were made to the OS/machine and just remove them or
- Just repave the machine. The explanation for this is in the `How to fix this` section, and boils down to cost.

## Troubleshooting Guide

`DateTime.ToString()` formats a date using the curren't user's Culture settings based on the `G` (generic) pattern - not the UI Culture, nor the System locale.

The fact that only one machine has a problem means there's no bug in .NET itself. My suspicions are:

- Modified user locale settings
- An installed [custom CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8#custom-cultures) replacement for en-US
- A Windows Embedded build with the modified cultures baked in.
- Any of that was done to "fix" Oracle HOME's weird behavior that ignores both client and server localization settings. Oracle itself offers two .NET drivers, a Fat client that ignores client/server settigns, uses `HOME` settings and takes an entire CD and a "Thin" one that works the way it should.

*Why Oracle?*

The code `return $"to_date('{datetime:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')";` suggest an attempt to "fix* the date format in a SQL query generated by string concatenation. The obvious question would be `why not use parameters?` but ...

I've encountered similar problems 10 years ago, when there was no Thin client. The UI could be Greek **OR** English, the database AMERICAN_AMERICA with Unicode fields. Oracle's client would mangle the text, even when passed as parameters, because the HOME, which has to match the database, wasn't Greek. No amount of locale tinkering could ever fix this - multiple UI locales that had to be "translated" to the same HOME locale.

The solution was to ditch the Oracle driver for Devart's, shaving at least 300MB from the installation and improving performance a *lot* due to the far faster driver. The Thin driver is supposed to ignore HOME and work properly too.

*Custom CultureInfos*

.NET allows the creation and installation of [custom cultures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8#custom-cultures). A custom culture can replace a built-in one simply by using the same name. Custom cultures have different LCID and CultureTypes values, which is why all the CultureInfo properties are needed. Installed cultures are stored in `%windir%\Globalization`

### What we know

**The Culture has been tampered with**. The output for `(Get-culture).DateTimeFormat` shows that the short date pattern is `dd-MMM-yy`, not the `M/d/yyyy` expected for `en-US`. Worse, it's a two-digit year which is *NOT* used anywhere, for obvious Y2K issues.

`(Get-Culture)|Format-List -Property *` will show if this is due to a custom CultureInfo.

*The formatted result is interesting*

`05/mm/42/mm/2020 11:42:54.3784272` looks like the result of a botched short date pattern, one that used mm (minutes)` instead of MM (months), and probably surrounded the actual format specifiers with some literals. A human modifying the local user settings would detect that. I suspect this was caused by code that generated multiple custom cultures in a loop

### Gathering information

- What Oracle driver is used and what specific version?
- *To check the Windows version*, this PowerShell query should return detaild build, patch and locale info :

```
systeminfo /fo csv | ConvertFrom-Csv | select OS*, System*, Hotfix*, *Locale | Format-List
```

- *To get the system locale* :

```
Get-WinSystemLocale |Format-List
```

`Get-WinSystemLocale` returns a CultureInfo object. `Format-List` displays a list of all root properties. Custom CultureInfo objects have [different `LCID` and `CultureTypes` values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8#custom-cultures).

Unfortunately, it's not recursive. To get the `DateTimeFormat` settings we need to use :

```
(Get-WinSystemLocale).DateTimeFormat |Format-List
```

- *To get the user's UI and thread locales* `Get-Culture` and `Get-UICulture` will return the CultureInfo objects used for parsing/formatting and the UI respectively, for the current user. Those are the ones that affect .NET too. The question's results show that the Culture and UI Culture names are the same but the behavior is different. We need both :

```
(Get-Culture)|Format-List -Property *
```

And

```
(Get-UICulture)|Format-List -Property *
```

- *To check for custom CultureInfos* we need to check the `%windir%\Globalization` folder. According to the [CustomCultureInfoAndRegionBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder?view=netframework-4.8) docs, that's where a custom culture's  `.nlp` file is stored.
- *Test various patterns* to isolate what's wrong. A custom Culture would affect what Get-Date -Format ' produces. We already know that CurrentCulture` in the app is affected.

The following PowerShell commands can be used to determine what exactly is affected :

```
Get-Date -Format G     # The Generic DateTime format used by ToString()
Get-Date -Format d     # Short date pattern, used as the first part of G
Get-Date -Format 'MM/dd/yyyy' # Explicit short format. Should show modifications to the date separator
```

If the short date format is different from the explicit format, we know what pattern was modified.

### How to fix this

- The **real** solution is to *Remove* the customization, whether it's a custom CultureInfo or something else. Use the Thin client at least, or a third-party one if the problem persists. This won't break other machines and they'll probably go faster too.
- Just *repave that machine*. It's only one after all. Even if it's a *real* MIL-STD hardened laptop that can withstand gun shock, the lost developer time and revenue is probably worth more than fixing it. Any fixes for that machine will break the app for every other machine too.
- Try to come up with a way to revert them - generate strings/values in such a way that the customized formatting ends up generating the correct values. And make sure this only runs when this particular customization is detected. Unrealistic unless there are a *lot* of such machines deployed in the field.
- Replace all .NET's string formatting code with explicit hand-coded formatting code. This would be a huge amount of work and extremely error prone. The app developers would also have to replicate the entire localization mechanism used by Windows without using any of its parts too.